# Steganography- Sound to Image Conversion

Tags: matlab, encryption

I was Trying to do a project based on this topic. The code is pasted below.

Encryption:

```
a=wavread('D:\hh.wav');
b=a(:,:);
x=1;
y=2000;
for i=1:100
   c=b(x:y);
   d=c';
   Aa(i,:)=d;
   x=x+2000;
   y=y+2000;
end
imwrite(Aa,'D:\Aa.jpg');
imwrite(Aa,'D:\Aa.png');
imwrite(Aa,'D:\Aa.tif');
wavwrite(D,42100,'D:\Aa.wav');
```

While doing so the final result is a 47 second wav file. Cannot encrypt more than that. Why is it so?

Comment: have you tried increasing the limit in your loop?

Comment: I tried using many possibilities of values but still the sound file remains at 47 seconds. I checked other source code which also had the same limit.